# Setup Let's Encrypt for a Gitlab instance behind a Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, ssl, gitlab, lets-encrypt, nginx-reverse-proxy

## Context

My company has a server dedicated to hosting the following services:

- **Gitlab**
- **Gitlab-runner** (one instance)
- **Nginx** (used as a reverse-proxy)

We are using **docker** and **docker-compose**.

Our Sysadmin is gone, and did not leave any documentation, notes or anything to understand his work. I (junior python dev) am trying temporarily take over and resolve urgent issues.

## Problem

This setup seems to be using self-signed certificate, and it seems that the certificate was manually renewed. That means that we have to ask people using our ticket system to change their Chrome/FF settings to accept `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`, which we can't. It also create issues for people wanting to checkout public repos through https.

I am trying to switch to a Let's Encrypt configuration, with auto-renewal.

My issue is that I have no idea how to do that. I have tried to follow [these instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html#primary-gitlab-instance), but it doesn't seem to change anything, which makes sense because.

## Questions

- Looking at our current (simplified) config files provided below, does the current setup even make sense?
- "Who" should be taking care of SSL? Gitlab or Nginx?
- How can I switch this config to using Let's Encrypt.

I hope those questions are not too broad, but, not really being a sysadmin or devops person, I'm a bit overwhelmed by the situation, so any beginner-friendly resource is also very welcome.

## Config files

### /srv/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '/srv/reverseproxy/config/:/etc/nginx/'
    networks:
      - default

  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:13.4.3-ce.0
    container_name: gitlab
    ports:
      - '22:22'
    hostname: gitlab
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
       external_url 'https://git.my-company.com'
       nginx['listen_port'] = 443
       nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
       nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/gitlab/git.my-company.com.pem"
       nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/gitlab/server-key.pem"
       nginx['ssl_protocols'] = "TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/ssl:/etc/ssl/certs/gitlab'
    networks:
      - default

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:v13.4.1
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    hostname: gitlab-runner
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
```

### /srv/reverseproxy/config/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream gitlab {
        server gitlab:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name git.my-company.com;
        return 301 https://git.my-company.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name git.my-company.com;

        ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/git.my-company.com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/server-key.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         https://gitlab;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nginx should be handling the certificate. Assuming Nginx and a self-hosted GitLab instance is on the same LAN, you can usually run this via HTTP, unless you have particularly stringent security requirements.

Comment: I wonder if it might be worth you trying Traefik instead of Nginx? It is Docker-friendly, and will do the Lets Encrypt registration for you automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've already figured this out, but I [wrote up a gist](https://gist.github.com/Erutan409/86d3ddd7f26d4d9cacb8011e4bd14b96) that is basically a copy/pasta of my environment for this exact scenario.